# Circle around link on hover

Tags: javascript, css, animation, hover

I'm having troubles figuring how to make a circle doodle(like a hand drawn sketch) appear on a link when hovered. In a perfect world it should be an animated svg path, but at this point just to appear works for me. Here is what exactly I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I've tried with background-image set to opacity:0 and when hover on opacity:1, but the issue is that when the link is longer the background image doesn't cover it all. Also I've tried with borders, but then I can't add a custom border shape, to look like a circle sketch you do with a pen.

Here is an example I found online: [click here](https://elementor.com/blog/introducing-animated-headline/) , the "Circle Me" example, under "Highlighted headlines"

I hope that this all makes sense,
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I did try, but my code isn't something special, just a list with links and pseudo background-image on hover for each, it works well only if the links are the same size, but if some is longer the background image gets weird. I'm not so savvy at these things, so I don't know how to ask my google question exactly either :D

Comment: So provide a [mcve] so that we can work with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can learn how to do that by using Chrome DevTools or other similars from your reference site.

```html
<div class='button'>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path fill="none" d="..." />
  </svg>
</div>
```

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button button {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}

.button svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.button path {
  stroke: #db3157;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 1500;
}

.button:hover path {
  animation: draw 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 1500;
  }

  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 1500 1500;
  }
}
```

Example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjwkyc5o/)

Answer (score 0):

**HTMl**

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="circle">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  padding: 4em 4em;
}
    .circle:hover {
    border-radius: 100%;        
    background: green;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:100px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Just try this and let me know if it is working for you. I wanted to help you.